# Given three distinct points on a sphere, find the unique round circle they live in

Tags: geometry, spheres, configuration-space

Say you have three (distinct) points on the unit sphere in Euclidean space

$$p_1, p_2, p_3 \in S^n = \{ x \in \mathbb R^{n+1} : |x| = 1 \}$$

I'd like to find, as efficiently and robustly as possible, a description of the unique round circle in $S^n$ that contains the three points.  By *round circle* I mean the intersection of an affine $2$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ with $S^n$.

I'm mostly interested in the $n=3$ case, although the $n>3$ cases are of some interest to me as well.

Off the top of my head the most sensible way to accomplish this would be:

1. Find the smallest-norm convex-combination of the $p_i$'s, i.e. solve
   $$\min \left\|\sum_i \alpha_i p_i\right\|, \hskip 1cm \sum_i \alpha_i = 1$$
   which is a calculus problem.
2. Replace the $p_i$'s by $p_i - q$ where $q$ is the above norm-minimizer.
3. Compute the orthogonal complement of $span(p_1, p_2, p_3)$.

If $q_1, q_2, \cdots, q_{n-2}$ is a basis for the orthogonal complement then that would give a system of equations describing the circle.

$$q_i \cdot (x-p_j) = 0$$

for all $i,j$ (these equations would technically be independent of j).

The nice thing about this setup is it's just linear algebra.  One problem with this solution is step (2) -- if the norm-minimizer results in a very small but non-zero norm there might be numerical instabilities.  In the application I have in mind, there will be (potentially) billions of such computations and these kinds of instabilities will be difficult to avoid.

The $n=2$ case has a rather cute, stable and efficient solution which (off the top of my head) I don't see how to generalize

$$Det \pmatrix{ x & y & z & 1 \cr \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & 1 \cr \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & 1 \cr \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & 1} = 0$$

where you plug the three points $p_1, p_2, p_3$ into the dotted rows.

If there was a more general solution of this kind, that would be wonderful as it solves the stability issue.  On top of that, it's a simple closed-form solution and my application could use a solution that is easily differentiated.  I don't *need* that, but it would be useful.

edit: I need an answer that gives the "universal bundle" description of the circle, i.e. an equation of the plane the circle lives in.  You could think of this as a point in the Grassmannian $G_{n+1,2}$ together with a vector in the orthogonal complement of the 2-dimensional subspace.  This is because I need ready access to the Hausdorff distance function (minimum distance) from points in the sphere to the circle.  i.e. a parametrization of the circle is not enough.

edit 2: in my comment below I refer to the *matrix formulation* of the Grassmannian.  In this formulation, the space of 2-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb R^n$ is the space of $n\times n$ matrices $A$ such that: $A^t = A, A^2=A, \text{ and } tr(A) = 2$.  From this perspective the matrix $A$ represents the orthogonal projection map onto its image, which is a $2$-dimensional subspace.

Comment: Is the Hausdorff distance function different from the Euclidean distance to the nearest point on the circle? If not, why is it hard to compute from an orthogonal basis of the subspace that the circle lies in?

Comment: @Rahul: 1) Yes. 2) It's not hard -- I describe a method to compute it in my question.  The point of my question is for a *robust* and simple answer.  One that is readily differentiated, for example. My answer is given by a piecewise smooth function, if you take the input to be the configuration space of three points on the sphere.  I would be interested to know if there is an answer that is, say, a rational polynomial on the configuration space -- say if you use the matrix formulation for the Grasmannian. In the n=2 case, clearly there is a polynomial answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A student helped me realize there are a few terrific answers to my question.
The flashiest, although not exactly what I want, is via the [Cayley-Menger formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Menger_determinant#).   This is the formula that gives the $n$-dimensional content of the convex hull of $(n+1)$-points in Euclidean space, as a determinant.

If you take the convex hull of $(n+1)$ points in $\mathbb R^m$, say the points $p_0, p_1, \cdots, p_n$ and let $d_{ij}$ be the distance between the $i$-th and $j$-th point, $d_{ij} = |p_i-p_j|$ then the $n$-dimensional content of the convex hull of these points is given by:

$$\mu_n (Hull(p_0,p_1,\cdots,p_n)) = \sqrt{\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(n!)^22^n}\begin{vmatrix} 
0 & d_{01}^2 & d_{02}^2 & \cdots & d_{0n}^2 & 1 \\
d_{01}^2 & 0 & d_{12}^2 & \cdots & d_{1n}^2 & 1 \\
d_{02}^2 & d_{12}^2 & 0 & \cdots & d_{2n}^2 & 1 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
d_{0n}^2 & d_{1n}^2 & d_{2n}^2 & \cdots & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 & 0
\end{vmatrix}\ }.$$

To relate this to my question, given three distinct points $p_1,p_2,p_3 \in S^3$ then the equation for $q \in S^3$ to be on the unique round circle containing the points $p_1,p_2,p_3$ is:

$$\mu_3(Hull(q,p_1,p_2,p_3)) = 0.$$

The problem with this is four points on a round circle is co-dimension two in the space of all 4-tuples of points in $S^3$, so $0$ can't be a regular value.  I'd really like the manifold to be the pre-image of a regular value.  But the normal bundle gives the clue, as 4-tuples that are on a round circle have a normal bundle induced from $TS^2$, the tangent bundle.

There is a map

$$f : C_4(S^3) \to S^2 \times S^2$$

where $C_4(S^3)$ is the space of distinct $4$-tuples of points in $S^3$, such that the diagonal $\Delta S^2 \subset S^2 \times S^2$ is a regular value, and $f^{-1}(\Delta S^2)$ is the subspace of $4$-tuples of points on a round circle.  $\Delta S^2 = \{(p,p) : p \in S^2 \}$.

The way you define the map is you use the quaternionic structure of $S^3$ to write $C_4(S^3) \simeq S^3 \times C_3(\mathbb R^3)$.  Then the 4-tuples of points on a round circle corresponds to the triples of points on a line in $\mathbb R^3$ (cross $S^3$). So the function is:

$$g : C_3(\mathbb R^3) \to S^2 \times S^2$$

given by
$$g(p_1,p_2,p_3) = \left(\frac{p_2-p_1}{|p_2-p_1|}, \frac{p_3-p_2}{|p_3-p_2|}\right)$$

There's two further variations of this function for the three different cyclic orderings of the four points. This is the kind of function I can use for my problem -- I need to do a Newton-method approximation.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(P)$ be the plane through $p_1,p_2,p_3$.

$(P)$ can be described as the set of points

$$p_{u,v}:=p_1+u(p_2-p_1)+v(p_3-p_1), \ \ \ \ \  \text{for} \ u,v \in \mathbb{R}.$$

Let $\Omega$ be the orthogonal projection of the origin $O$ onto $(P)$ (obtained for example by minimizing the norm of $p_{u,v}$).

$\Omega$ is naturally the center of the circumscribed circle to triangle $p_1,p_2,p_3$.

It suffices then to orthonormalize the (vector) basis $\{(p_2-p_1),(p_3-p_1)\}$ into the (vector) basis $\{q_1,q_2\}$ to be able to describe the circle in the following way:

$$p=\Omega+r \cos(t) q_1 + r \sin(t)q_2, \ \ \ t \in [0,2 \pi]$$

with $r>0$ defined by equality $\vec{O\Omega}^2+r^2=1.$

Remark: this works in any dimension.

Comment: I should have mentioned it but in an answer I need convenient access to the tubular neighbourhood "distance function" from the circle, i.e. the Hausdorff distance.    Although I occasionally need access to a parametrization of the circle, it is not a task that will be needed often-enough to bog things down, and there are no stability issues with these types of computations.

Comment: You may transfer your issue into either a) a conformal geometry setting (in particular by using a generalization of stereographical projection) or b) a  projective geometry setting (it is already the case - in an implicit way - when you use the $4 \times 4$ determinant for 3D Euclidean geometry; in the latter case, I recommand you the book "Uncertain Projective Geometry" Stephan Heuel Springer LNCS 3008.